# splitting the values in one column and a set of rows evenly and proportionally among other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know, I confused you.

I have this data:

[image]

For the three items that are NULL, I need to:

1. Add them (1828.94 + 772.90 + 0.00).
2. Split this total among each ItemID evenly and proportionally based on quantity for each.

Note that there are ItemIDs that are the same but this is OK.

Basically the end result will be the same columns without the 3 rows that have ItemID = NULL and the Amount column will be increased by some because I'm splitting the amount among the ItemIDs.

I'm having a really hard time doing this without having to do a bunch of loops.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: How do you expect to update the ItemID column using Amount Column ?? I understand that you want to equally divide the sum of amount where ItemID and Qty is null but how would you update the ItemID column using Amount column ???

Comment: I could dump this into another table. Anything I would have to do to get this working I'm able to do. I'm using temp tables to hold this data as I'm processing it.

Comment: Lets start again shall we? So you want to Insert these rows into another table, delete these rows from this table, and then the Update  statement using the amount column... am I right ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the apportioned amount with this query:

```
select t.*,
       x.AmountToSplit * t.qty / x.TotalQty as AmountToAdd
from t cross join
     (select sum(case when itemId is null then amount end) as AmountToSplit,
             sum(case when itemId is not null then Qty end) as TotalQty
      from t
     ) x
where t.itemId is not null;
```

If you actually want to update the amounts, then use this as an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             x.AmountToSplit * t.qty / x.TotalQty as AmountToAdd
      from t cross join
           (select sum(case when itemId is null then amount end) as AmountToSplit,
                   sum(case when itemId is not null then Qty end) as TotalQty
            from t
           ) x
      where t.itemId is not null
     )
update toupdate
    set Amount = Amount + AmountToAdd;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. AmountToSplit is coming back blank for all rows and the amount is not really changing.

Comment: @Rj.  . . . Did my last edit fix the problem?  I had left in a `where` clause that shouldn't have been in the final version.

Comment: you are the man! this did the trick. though my math is slightly more complicated. but i can take it from here. thanks gordon!

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for what you're trying to do?

```
DECLARE @NullAmounts MONEY,
        @RowCount INT

SELECT @NullAmounts = SUM(CASE WHEN ItemID IS NULL THEN Amount ELSE 0 END),
       @RowCount = COUNT(*)
FROM Table

UPDATE Table
SET Amount = Amount + (@NullAmounts / @RowCount)
WHERE
    ItemID IS NOT NULL
```

Of course, after you've run the update, you can `DELETE` the rows so you don't have them return in a `SELECT` statement.

```
DELETE Table
WHERE ItemID IS NULL
```

Comment: I think this worked. I'm double checking the numbers to make sure. Will report back in a few.